# Having trouble connecting to wireless network

Tags: 11.10, wireless, thinkpad

I have problems with connecting to wireless network - eudroam. According to the instructions I should just enter login and password, and that is it. However, later Ubuntu asks me about login information again. I talked to technical staff, they told me that on Windows, you just login to network and accept installation SSL certificate (menu pop ups automatically). But under Ubuntu nothing happens. How can I fix it? Thank you!

**Edit:** I'm on a ThinkPad E420.

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 2):

There are known issues with the Realtek 819x Wireless N adapters used in Thinkpad 420's and 520's. I am running into the same issues and may just replace the wireless adapter with an Intel component. The wireless gave me no problems in Windows 7 but it looks like we'll have to wait for a stable driver to be released for Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether its asking for the network password or your system/user password. Make sure you're providing the correct one.